# 2d array use in the kernel

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

In the CUDA examples i read, I don't find any direct use of 2D array notation [][] in the kernel code when the array is in the global memory unlike when it is in the shared memory, e.g.  matrix multiplication. Is there any performance related reason behind this?

Also, i read in a old thread that the following code is incorrect

```
int **d_array;
cudaMalloc(  (void**)&d_array , 5 * sizeof(int*) );  

for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) 
{ 
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_array[i],10 * sizeof(int));
}
```

According to the author, "once the main thread assigns memory on the device the main thread loses access to it, that is, it can only be accessed within kernels. So, When you try call cudaMalloc on the 2nd dimension of the array it throws an "Access violation writing location" exception."

I don't understand what the author really means; actually,  i find the above code correct

Thank your for your help

SS

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any performance related reason behind this?

Yes, a doubly-subscripted array normally requires an extra pointer lookup, i.e. an extra memory read, before the data referenced can be accessed.  By using "simulated" 2D access:

```
int val = d[i*columns+j];
```

instead of:

```
int val = d[i][j];
```

then only a single memory read access is required.  The proper indexing is computed directly, rather than requiring the read of a row-pointer.  GPUs generally have lots of compute capability compared to memory bandwidth.

> I don't understand what the author really means; actually, i find the above code correct

The code is in fact incorrect.

This operation:

```
cudaMalloc(  (void**)&d_array , 5 * sizeof(int*) );
```

creates a single contiguous allocation on the device, of length equal to 5 pointers storage, and takes the starting address of that allocation, and stores it in the host memory location associated with `d_array`.  That is what `cudaMalloc` does: it creates a device allocation of the requested length, and stores the *starting device address of that allocation* in the provided **host memory** variable.

So let's deconstruct what is being asked for here:

```
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_array[i],10 * sizeof(int));
```

This says, create a device allocation of length `10*sizeof(int)` and store the starting address of it in the location `d_array[i]`.  But the location associated with `d_array[i]` *is on the device*, not the host, and requires *dereferencing* of the `d_array` pointer to actually access it, to store something there.

`cudaMalloc` does not do this.  You cannot ask for the starting address of the device allocation to be stored in device memory.  You can only ask for the starting address of the device allocation to be stored in **host memory**.

```
&d_array
```

is a pointer to host memory.

```
&d_array[i]
```

is a pointer to device memory.

The canonical 2D array worked example is now referenced in the [cuda tag info link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding you comment under the 2nd cudaMalloc call, i think you meant that *the starting address* of  10*sizeof(int) allocated on the device should be stored in d_array[i]. I thought all compilers, CUDA included, translate the doubly subscripted array into a single sub-scripted one; hence access to doubly scripted array element should not be slower. Another question that was not covered in your answer, i notice that 2-d array structures are often used in the kernels when the arrays are stored in shared memory. Would it be better to use 1-d array instead? Thank you

Comment: Yes, regarding the starting address, that is what I meant, and I have edited the answer accordingly. Regarding the doubly-subscripted array, I'm pretty sure what you are suggesting is entirely impossible for the posted code.  First of all, the starting pointer is a **double** pointer, it only has meaning if it is dereferenced to create a single pointer.  As a simple counter-proof, consider that there is nothing that requires the array width to be constant, for the posted code.  Instead of `10*sizeof(int)`, I could just as easily have written `i*sizeof(int)`, and it would be entirely legal.

Comment: And there is no way the compiler could figure out arbitrary row-by-row indexing to avoid the double-dereference.

Comment: As a further proof-point, the doubly-subscripted allocation scheme shown here does not even guarantee that the underlying allocation is contiguous -- no compiler can work out a scheme to work around that from an indexing calculation perspective.  The doubly subscripted access depicted here *must* be accomplished via an extra pointer read.  I don't believe there is any compiler magic that can work around that, CUDA or otherwise.

Comment: Regarding the 2D array in shared memory, I have seen that most commonly with a static allocation, not a dynamic one.  With a static allocation, the width of the array is known at compile time, and it is guaranteed to be a contiguous allocation. Therefore the compiler can, and will, figure out the necessary indexing arithmetic at compile time, without requiring a separate pointer access.  Handling dynamically allocated arrays vs. statically allocated arrays under the hood is quite different, from a compiler perspective.